# Reset ACLs in NFS4/ZFS network share

Tags: zfs, opensolaris, nfs4, openindiana

How can I reset the ACLs on a ZFS file system on OpenIndiana that is exported via NFS4 and replace it with inherited permissions? Basically, I want to do the equivalent of `icacls "C:\path\to\folder" /reset /T /C` on Windows on this machine. However, neither the chmod command on OpenIndiana nor the nfs4_setacl seems to allow for deleting all ACLs although the client correctly interprets inherited ACLs if a node does not have an own one.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all non trivial ACLs in ZFS with the following: `chmod A- filename`

Source: [Solaris ZFS Administration Guide: Using ACLs and Attributes to Protect ZFS Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/ftyxi.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: chmod A- replaces the ACL with a default ACL representing the permission bits. I want to remove the ACL completely.

Comment: That is precisely what "chmod A-" is doing. The "default ACL representing the permission bits" is precisely what you got with a file having no ACL set.

Comment: But if I use Windows on the SMB share, I can also remove also the default ACL and it still works on all OSes. If I investigate the ACLs via Windows, there is a difference: when using chmod A-, the ACL is not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to set 'aclinherit' peoperty on zfs volume:

```
zfs set aclinherit=passthrough tank/volume
```